# Laravel 5.1: Search not returning any data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am having one multi-select field. In my search.blade.php.

```
HTML::select2(
        'test[]', 
        trans('file.test'),
        trans("attr/file.test"), 
        Input::old('test[]'), 
        true)
```

and my scopeSearchFilter in model have following code.

```
if($request->has('test')) $query = $query->where('test',$request->get('test'));
```

I am not able to return array. It is returning nothing.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are defining the select as a array `test[]`. But in your query, you are not accounting for multiple selections. You can either do:

```
$query = $query->whereIn('test', $request->get('test'));
```

Or update the query to use OR to search all terms selected in the input.